# Unresolved External including the aux_klib kernel library

Tags: c++, c, linker, driver, kmdf

Good Afternoon, so I have a question about including the aux_klib library in my Kernel Mode Driver, for some reason I get the same error for all aux_klib functions.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol AuxKlibInitialize referenced in function "unsigned char __cdecl Main(struct MainInfo*)" (?MainInfo@@YAEPEAU__MainInfo@@@Z)
```

I did #pragma comment(lib, "aux_klib.lib") in my project and no luck, also the driver is coded in cpp. I also added the lib to my project and made sure it was x64 as that is the projects build architecture. I also tried including the function via extern "C" with out the header and just the lib but no luck, I also added all the library paths to the linker settings and what not. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: for research this kind of error you need add linker option [/VERBOSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) or how minimum `/VERBOSE:LIB` and view in output - are `aux_klib.lib` used by linker. *AuxKlibInitialize* exist in x64 version of *aux_klib.lib*

Comment: I added /VERBOSE:LIB to my command lines options and its still the same linker error no added output, also I opened aux_klib.lib x64 in IDA and looked at the exports and they all seem to be there.

Comment: this option of course not fix error, it for diagnostic. `no added output` - what you mean - are no any messages is printed by link ?! not believe. you use msvc for build ? use  `/VERBOSE` and look for linker output - are he search for *aux_klib.lib* may be you used */nodefaultlib* option. in this case `#pragma comment(lib, "aux_klib.lib")` will be have no effect. you need direct add *aux_klib.lib* to linker input

Comment: did as you said got rid of the /nodefaultlib and still same error no extra output
http://prntscr.com/f4ttcc
http://prntscr.com/f4ttgy
http://prntscr.com/f4ttxt

Comment: but are you add `/VERBOSE` ? in msvc - *Properties -> Linker -> General -> Show Progress*

Comment: Still same result.

Comment: in this case don't know what is going wrong , but when you really set /VERBOSE linker option - linker **must** print many additional information

Comment: you can also remove *Properties -> Linker -> General -> Suppress Startup Bunner* - for view linker actual command line - are /VERBOSE exist in it ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f4u0nn also supress startup banner is off, nothing changed xD

Comment: don't know why linker output not shown for you. when i remove `/NOLOGO` and set `/VERBOSE` - i view many linker messages - `Linking...Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version .. Searching libraries..Finished searching libraries..` etc. why this not shown for you - hard to say

Answer (score 2):

```
Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies add "AUX_KLIB.LIB"
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with linking `Aux_klib.lib`, so I set `/VERBOSE:Lib`.

> Right click on the project -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Show
>   Progress

As I understand it, `For Libraries Searched /VERBOSE:Lib` shows the libraries search and I've noticed that `Aux_klib.lib` is not in that search.
And I noticed another thing in the output, `/NODEFAULTLIB` is passed in the command line as well.

As @RbMm says,

> are he search for aux_klib.lib may be you used /nodefaultlib option.
>   in this case #pragma comment(lib, "aux_klib.lib") will be have no
>   effect.

So I changed `Ignore All Default Libraries`

> Right click on the project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore
>   All Default Libraries

to `No` and everything linked and compiled perfectly.

## TL;DR

In short, try to change `Ignore All Default Libraries` under `Linker` to `No` and use `#pragma comment(lib, "aux_klib.lib")`.