# Issues linking Aux_Klib.h

Tags: c++, wdk, windows-kernel

Good morning, folks!

I was hoping to enumerate all the loaded kernel modules with AuxKlibQueryModuleInformation.

I have the latest WDK installed and is up to date, using VS2019. My code is this so far:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <aux_klib.h>

extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING)
{
    --snipped--
    Status = AuxKlibInitialize();
    --snipped--
}
```

The error I get for this is: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol AuxKlibInitialize referenced in function DriverEntry.

What I am trying to do is just get a list of the loaded kernel modules and I read doing it this way would be better than using undocumented functions. If anyone has done this, I'm all ears for any alternatives or pointers?

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816953/unresolved-external-including-the-aux-klib-kernel-library) and did what the user did, but I am still unable to get this going. I also noticed that when it's searching for libraries, I'm not seeing Aux_Klib.lib included or in the output or whatever. Not sure if that helps any, but doing everything that post mentioned didn't work. I also tried linking it directly using the full path and still, nothing happens. It also mentions downloading an object library but that is 404. I'm not quite sure what else to do. Can I get some help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I ended up just sticking to ZwQuerySystemInformation. Would still like to know what's up with Aux_Klib though

Comment: *Library - Aux_klib.lib*

Comment: Right, but it will still error.